# How to match a list of dates to a pattern?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, pattern-matching

I have a Python `list` of `tuples` with three objects: a `string` (ex: title), `date` and another `string` (ex: a name).

**Example:**

```
scientific_works = [
    ('SW 1', datetime.date(2000, 10, 15), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 2', datetime.date(2000, 11, 3), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 3', datetime.date(2000, 11, 4), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 4', datetime.date(2000, 12, 1), 'auth 1'),
]
```

**Then I have a pattern:**

from `date` until `date`, (at least) `int` items from `list` per `int` days/weeks/months/years

Example:

```
from  datetime.date(2000, 11, 1)
until datetime.date(2000, 11, 30)
1 item per day
```

What I would like the algorithm to do:

- Given that list and that pattern, do the filtered items match the rules?

In the case of examples, this pattern would match 2 items, all of them matching the rule here: `1 item complete per day`, however, since there aren't `an item` for each day block, the algorithm would return `false`.

Another example:

- Is there (at least) Int_1 amount of items (works) per Int_2 (day/week/month)?

  - 1 work per day would mean at least 1 item per 1 day block of given the date range. 2 works per week would mean, at least 2 works each week (or 7 day block) of date range.

I can iterate over the list and find out which items match `from` and `until` pattern, of course.

However, I am really confused over matching them with the rest of the rules to see if its a positive or a negative match.

My question:

- How can I construct an algorithm, provide it with a list and a pattern of rules (x items per y day OR week OR month OR year), and see if it matches or not?

I am working on a little component for an application where given a certain data (list) and rules (pattern), if an author unlocks a reward or not.

I have completed udacity's several Python classes, including most of algorithms but really can not find my way around this.

So far I thought of this:

1. Filter list items with the given date range.
2. Calculate the range blocks within the range: 1 day from d1 until d2 = 5 days - 1 week from d1 until d2 = 3 weeks
3. Create a loop in range of `int` calculated above.
4. Convert weeks, months, years to days in each step of the loop.
5. Add the amount to the start date and see if items match the date range.
6. Add the amount to next start of date range and repeat.

However, this doesn't work and I don't think converting blocks to days is efficient at all.

Thank you.

Comment: Now it's back to the most common question on stackoverflow. What have you tried?

Comment: @alKid, thank you for your comment. I implemented first filtering of date-range. The rest, I drew schemas on paper and tried to come up with a process (algorithm) but I am failing as I don't know where to begin.

Comment: when do the time periods start at the start date or at their calendar date? For example, does `[date(2000, 6, 15), date(2001, 1, 1)]` list match the pattern: `from  datetime.date(2000, 6, 14)
until datetime.date(2001, 6, 1) 2 item per year`?

Comment: It doesn't matter if end date and begin date is inclusive or not. Basically the algorithm is to see if, say a scientist, published a paper or more every month between from-until dates OR if a biker practices once every week OR if a student went to school once a day for 5 days. The date range to filter is simplest and I covered but the other parts -- matching patter to list true/false is proving to be difficult. Thank you, any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @Phil: It is not about inclusiveness. The list contains two different calendar years - *one* date per year. But the difference between the dates is less when a year (as in < 365.25 days) i.e., *two* items per year. Do you see the contradiction? Could you answer the question from the previous comment: Does the list match the pattern or not?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, I replied from a mobile device, I'm sorry to misreading the dates in your comment. Allow me to answer now: The time period entered (2000-6-14, 2001-6-1) is less than a year (352 days). Therefore, the algorithm should *not* work and give an error. If X item per Y d/m/w/y is requested, the date range should cover at least 1 full block (of days, weeks, months or year). And if the date range is longer than 1 range block but shorter than 2, then it should round itself to shorter one (1). So 2 items per year for 1.5 years should check if 2 articles were published for a year and stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the pattern is:

```
from  start_date
until end_date
X items per period
```

then to find out whether `scientific_works` matches the pattern, an analog of [`numpy.histogram()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) could be used:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

ts = datetime.date.toordinal # or any monotonic numeric `date` function 
hist = np.histogram(map(ts, (date for title, date, name in scientific_works)),
                    bins=map(ts, daterange(start_date, end_date, period))[0]
does_it_match = all(x >= X for x in hist)
```

where:

```
def daterange(start_date, end_date, period):
    d = start_date
    while d < end_date:
        yield d
        d += period
```

Example:

```
>>> from datetime import date, timedelta
>>> list(daterange(date(2000, 1, 1), date(2000, 2, 1), timedelta(days=7)))
[datetime.date(2000, 1, 1), datetime.date(2000, 1, 8),
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 15), datetime.date(2000, 1, 22),
 datetime.date(2000, 1, 29)]
```

Comment: the procedures do seem work as all my test cases have passed. Thank you very much. Can you explain if you have the chance, how you came up with the solution? How did you figure it out and why it works? I will be reading more about numpy now. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil: Once I understood that you need *number of items per period*; it was easy to come up with `histogram()` that returns *number of samples per bin*. Just transform `date` into a number and you've got the solution. btw, if you don't use `numpy` in other parts of your code then you can replace `numpy.histogram()` by its analog e.g., with something `itertools.groupby()`-based.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post a better example of the rules that the match has to follow?  Are you looking for a certain number of items *per author* per time period?  Or are you looking for certain entries over a time period and then finding who they belong to?  That will effect the sort.

I think you will end up having to use a sort algorithm on this data, which is not horrible if you go about it the right way.

From the bottom part of your question I think that if you are searching for x items per n time-periods (day/week/month) and then determining the authors it might be a bit messy.  If you have a finite number of authors it might be easier to flip that around and create an array for each author and store the item and date in there.  Then you just run a testing loop over each author that checks all their entries to see if they fit the requirements.

For Python classes, MIT OpenCourseware's 6.00 Introduction to Computer Science and Programming is very good.  It can be found at http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/>

Comment: Hello @willianth. I am sorry if my explanation was not clear enough. Thank you for having an interest. If you permit, I'd like to elaborate: The author in the list is redundant, it has no effect. Given a list, I want to first get the items from day D1 until day D2, which I can do. Afterwards, I need to see if the list obtained matches a ruleset: Is there (at least) Int_1 amount of items (works) per Int_2 (day/week/month)? Ex: 1 work per day would mean at least 1 item per 1 day block of given the date range. 2 works per week would mean, at least 2 works each week (or 7 day block) of date range.

Comment: @Phil: please, don't put relevant info in the comments. [Update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19875379/4279) where others can see it without the need to read everything on the page.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, already done so ;-) wording might differ though, I shall perhaps add these word-for-word as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would use following design: main generator function which iterates over sequence of works and yields "good" ones; and a set of pluggable filters which implement particular rules, such as date range, N items per day, per week, per month, etc.

Following is an small example to illustrate the idea:

```
from datetime import date
from pprint import pprint

scientific_works = [
    ('SW 1', date(2000, 10, 15), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 2', date(2000, 11, 3), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 3', date(2000, 11, 4), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 4', date(2000, 11, 5), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 5', date(2000, 12, 1), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 6', date(2000, 12, 15), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 7', date(2000, 12, 18), 'auth 1'),
    ('SW 8', date(2000, 12, 22), 'auth 1'),
]

def filter_works(works, *filters):
    for work in works:
        good = True
        for fil in filters:
            good = good and fil(work)
        if good:
            yield work

class RangeFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, from_date, to_date):
        self.from_date = from_date
        self.to_date = to_date

    def __call__(self, work):
        return self.from_date <= work[1] <= self.to_date


class WorksPerMonthFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, limit):
        self.limit = limit
        self._current_month = date.min
        self._current_number = 0

    def __call__(self, work):
        month = date(work[1].year, work[1].month, 1)
        if month == self._current_month:
            self._current_number += 1
        else:
            self._current_month = month
            self._current_number = 1
        return self._current_number <= self.limit


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pprint(list(filter_works(scientific_works, RangeFilter(date(2000, 10, 1), date(2000, 11, 30)), WorksPerMonthFilter(2))))
    pprint(list(filter_works(scientific_works, RangeFilter(date(2000, 10, 1), date(2000, 12, 31)), WorksPerMonthFilter(2))))
    pprint(list(filter_works(scientific_works, RangeFilter(date(2000, 10, 1), date(2000, 12, 31)), WorksPerMonthFilter(3))))
```

Comment: Hello @alexanderlukanin13. Thank you for your example. It can be a starting point for me for implementing the filtering. However, the part that confuses me is implementing "if it matches the pattern" as in, from x until y, is  there Z amount of work per Q day/month/week etc. What do you suggest think I can do then to verify?

Comment: Do you want to check, for example, if there are at least 2 works each month?
The algorithm will be very similar. You just need to store overall state (boolean) in each Filter. After sequence is processed, you can inspect each Filter's status and combine them by and/or/whatever logic you want to get final result.

Comment: you can simplify filter_works as `return (work for work in works if all(fil(work) for fil in filters))`

Comment: Note that `all` will not execute _all_ filters - it stops at first `False`.